# ReportViewer 11.0.0.0 and SubreportProcessing Event not Firing

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a number of reports with subreport working well with ReportViewer 10.0.0 and as soon as I upgraded to ReportViewer 11.0.0.0 the subreport processing event is not firing.

Has anyone had a similar experience.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the upgrade of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms (9.0 => 11.0), in our case, the event is firing. But the datasource provided for the first subreport is used for render all the others subreports...

If the SubreportProcessing handler is not executing, try without the event's unmap instruction.

AddHandler Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf LocalReport_SubreportProcessing

Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("dsToto", ...))

Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

'With the following line, the unmap occurs before the end of rendering : the event handler is not called

'RemoveHandler Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf LocalReport_SubreportProcessing

Comment: Thanks Stephane, Sorry the rest of my comments got cut off. I think you are right, I am using the event to attach filtered version of a datasource to each sub-report. I will try and attach the datasource before the report is rendered and see if that works. Once again thank you for your advise.